# Activate spell check for modern pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, modern-team-site, spellchecker

Is there a way to enable spell checking for modern pages?
Of course I can simply use the spelling checker integrated in the web browser. But it is not as smart as the one from Word...

The publishing features are activated!

Site Features:
[image: Site Features]

Site Collection Features:
[image]

And it doesn't work...

[image: edit page]

Answer (score 0):

spell check shall work by default in SharePoint Online like the pic below
[image]

If not working, have a try to activate the publishing feature and have a try.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work... (I have updated my post)

Comment: @SharePointNewbie, it may be better for you to submit a service request about this. I tested with several sites with/without the feature, the spell check always work.